# two people one excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

My colleague and I are working on an Excel file but just one of us can use at a time. Is there a way to use this file with all features of excel 2007 simultaneously? If not, can an access file help us to solve this issue?

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to work on the same document at the same time, because you will inevitably produce conflicting versions sooner or later. I would suggest using a Dropbox folder, which is shared between you and your colleague. If you open the document, you can see if the other is working on it (with the Dropbox button, which is a default MS Office-plugin of Dropbox).

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask this kind of question. This site is for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, if you make it shared, a lot of Excel's functionality is disabled (eg. pivot tables, charts, etc.).

The solution is using anything that is designed for multiple users (eg. any database, yes, even Access, or Google Docs, or OneNote, or a big piece of paper and two pens - depends on what you need it for).

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the same file simultaneously, seeing the changes the other person makes won't be shown on your end. So let's say you entered data in a cell, and your colleague does the same in the same cell, it will encounter problems. So excel prevents this by limiting this to 1 user. I'm not sure about access.

Comment: Yes you can edit simultaneously, but you have to make the file shared. And that disables much of Excel's functionality.

Comment: Yeah it disables much of excels functionality. So that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google spreadsheets are particularly good for simultaneous editing by multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

As others have alluded to, it is NOT a good idea to share Excel resources.  If you REALLY want to do this, you can try to share the Workbook.

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/share-workbooks.html

Eventually, though, this will cause corruption.  A better idea is to use Access for shared needs (split and share your Access database).

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74

Or, better, use SQL Server, and a ASP.NET user interface.  This is probably way beyond where you are now, but you could certainly learn the nuts and bolts of these technologies, and get up to speed with these kinds of things pretty quickly.  You should always try to use the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

No, you cannot.
You can try using some syncing services like Google Drive or Dropbox, but that would leave the file corrupted when you have two people editing at the same time. Excel is not designed for that purpose. What you should do is to move all your work to **[Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/)**. It wouldn't take so long to do so.